# Is it possible to replace data in a column in ms-access?

Tags: sql, ms-access

In ms-access database, is it possible to write an sql query to replace the number in a column with a number obtained by adding 2 to this original number. ie, all numbers in  a column should be replaced by the original number plus 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UPDATE myTable SET myColumn = myColumn + 2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE YourTable 
SET 
    NUMBER = NUMBER + 2
```

If you don't do a where your going to do the whole lot. So if you are doing this from a form you need something like

```
WHERE id = ' & me.ID
```